# Inconsistent circular dependency with constructor+setter injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have following beans in my application

```
@Component
public class Main {

    private A a;

    @Inject
    public Main(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}

@Component
public class A {
    private B b;

    @Inject
    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

}

@Component
public class B {
    private A a;

    @Inject
    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

}
```

Component scan is for the package where this three classes were placed.
The above beans works in some environment and fails in other environment  with circular dependency while create bean Main
Why is this circular dependency not very consistent?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your bean A depends on bean B, and bean B depends on bean A. First of all, I would suggest rethinking your design. However, there are workarounds like using @Postconstruct, or @Lazy.
Here's a good reference, which explains what happens and different ways to solve the problem: http://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Comment: I know that its bad design.But i am trying to understand why it is inconsistent?Why i dont face this error always?

Comment: Could you provide some information? When does it fail? When doesn't? Do you have a sample working code?

Comment: this are similar http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/115998-circular-dependency-identification-inconsistent https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14307